# Why $(1-\omega)^{\varphi(m)} = p\mathbb{Z}[\omega]?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

> Let $\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{m}}$ for $m = p^r$ a prime power.  Why do we have $$(1-\omega)^{\varphi(m)} = p\mathbb{Z}[\omega]?$$ (Here $(1-\omega)$ means the principal ideal).

I know that $$\prod_{p \nmid k}(1-\omega^k) = p.$$  But I'm not sure how to use this fact. Maybe if $(1-\omega) = (1-\omega^k)$? but i dont see why that should be true.

Comment: Ohhh, $1-\omega^k = (1-\omega)(1+\omega+...+\omega^{k-1})$ so at least $(1-\omega^k) \subset (1-\omega)$...

Comment: And then I guess $(1-\omega) = (1-\omega^k)(1+ \omega^k + \omega^{2k} + ... + \omega^{(m-1)k})$ where $m = k^{-1} mod p^r$.